# position dodge not working with geom bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this bar plot

```
group = c("A","A","B","B")
value = c(1,2,3,4)
day = c(1,2,1,2)
dat = data.frame(group = group , value = value, day = day)
dat

ggplot(data=dat, aes(x = group, y = value, fill = day)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

and it is stacked but I don't want it stacked. Instead I'd like to use `position = "dodge"` to make the days stacked next to each other FOR EACH group.  any idea how to get the days next to each other for each group?

Comment: (1) `day` should not be numeric, (2) there is nothing to dodge; `day` is constant within `group`. Change it to `c(1,2,1,2)`, and try `fill = factor(day)`.

Comment: If your real data have a structure similar to the data in your question, you might find this more effective than a bar plot: `ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=day, y=value, color=group)) + geom_line() + geom_point() `.